# How can I implement a recursive insert function for a binary tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I want to emphasize that I am specifically dealing with a binary tree, not a binary search tree (BST). The only requirements I have for this tree is that it should be balanced and insert children from left to right. I do not care about it being ordered or having duplicates.

I ask this because most of the time I find examples of inserts for a binary tree, it is for a BST instead where there are no duplicates and we order things in a way that values less than the root node are stored at root.left and values that are higher than the root node get stored and root.right. I know how to implement that already, but would like to learn how to implement a basic insert for a regular binary tree. It is the recursive aspect that I am having difficulties with.

Also, I know it would be easier to do this using a data structure like a queue or a list but I would first like to attempt it without one.

Here is my insert function:

```
    TreeNode insert(int data, TreeNode root, boolean isLeft){

    if(root == null){
        root = new TreeNode(data);
    }
    else if(root.left == null){
        root.left = new TreeNode(data);
    }
    else if(root.right == null){
        root.right = new TreeNode(data);

    }
    else{
        if(isLeft){
            insert(data, root.right, false);
        }
        else{
            insert(data, root.left, true);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

And here is what I am using to initialize the tree:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);

    boolean isLeft = false;

    for(int i = 2; i < 11; i++){
        isLeft = !isLeft;
       root = root.insert(i, root, isLeft);
    }
```

This produces a tree that looks like this:

```
│       ┌── 7
│   ┌── 3
│   │   └── 5
│   │       └── 9
└── 1
    │       ┌── 10
    │   ┌── 6
    │   │   └── 8
    └── 2
        └── 4
```

Which does not insert systematically from left to right. Ideally it would look like this:

```
│       ┌── 7
│   ┌── 3
│   │   └── 6
│   │        
└── 1
    │       
    │   ┌── 5
    │   │   └── 10
    └── 2   ┌── 9
        └── 4
            └── 8
```

The only reason it is numbered here is because I am using a for loop to create values but I do not care about number order, just left-to-right balance.

Comment: What is the purpose for this tree? If there is no meaning to where a value sits in that tree, then how will it benefit anything useful?

Comment: That looks balanced and somewhat systematic to me. Can you show the expected result?

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect what I am looking for out of the tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would maintain the *size* of the tree then the binary representation of that size (plus 1) reveals which path to take to the next insertion point.

For instance, if the current tree is:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
  /
 4
```

then its size+1 is 5, which in binary is 101. Ignore the most significant bit -- which is always 1 -- and then interpret a 0 as left, and 1 as right. And indeed that is the path for reaching the spot where the next value must be injected:

```
          1
(left)  /   \
       2     3
      / \ (right)
     4   5
```

Not the question, but it is overkill to have a `root` parameter, when the function is a *method* on a `TreeNode` instance, so you already *have* the root (i.e. `this`).

Here is an implementation -- not recursive, as it is quite straightforward to do iteratively:

```
    TreeNode insert(int data, int size) {
        TreeNode root = this;
        String bits = Integer.toBinaryString((size + 1) >> 1).substring(1);
        for (char bit : bits.toCharArray()) {
            root = bit == '1' ? root.right : root.left;
        }
        if (root.left == null) {
            root.left = new TreeNode(data);
        } else {
            root.right = new TreeNode(data);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Call as:

```
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
        int size = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i < 11; i++){
            root.insert(i, size++);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully and it is an approach that I never would have considered. Someone asked earlier what the purpose of this, and to be honest, there is none. I just wanted to see how an implementation of this would look, and yours looks great.